# Count unique values in dataframe which fall into given datetime interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe:

```
ID           time_begin               time_end
A1      2019-04-04 08:04:56      2019-04-04 08:15:26
A11     2019-04-04 08:14:22      2019-04-04 08:42:04
BB      2019-04-04 08:44:53      2019-04-04 09:02:11
C5      2019-04-04 09:01:12      2019-04-04 09:22:07
C1      2019-04-04 09:03:51      2019-04-04 09:34:20
DD      2019-04-04 09:22:42      2019-04-04 09:42:42
DD1     2019-04-04 09:25:42      2019-04-04 09:47:55
```

So, I want to get maximum of numbers of ID which cross half-hour values of timestamp within a sample of "time" of 20 minutes.

- So for **timestamp from 8:00 to 8:20** we get 2 unique ID (2019-04-04 08:04:56 and 2019-04-04 08:14:22). But only ID A11 cross 8:20 (because it lasts from 2019-04-04 08:14:22 to 2019-04-04 08:42:04), so we count only it.
- For **timestamp from 8:20 to 8:40** we get 0 unique ID.
- For **timestamp from 8:40 to 9:00** we get 1 unique ID BB. It crosses 9:00 value, so we count it.
- For **timestamp from 9:00 to 9:20** we get 2 ID C5 and C1.
- For **timestamp from 9:20 to 9:40** we get 2 ID DD and DD1 because both cross 9:40. Desired result is to get it as dataframe:

```
time                    ID_num
2019-04-04 08:00:00        1
2019-04-04 08:20:00        0
2019-04-04 08:40:00        1
2019-04-04 09:00:00        2
2019-04-04 09:20:00        2
```

How could i do that? I tricky part is that counting IDs only if they cross values 8:00, 8:20, 8:40,.....

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it can be done with a cross merge and query:

```
# set up the time intervals
intervals = pd.date_range(df.time_begin.min().floor('20min'), 
                          df.time_end.max().ceil('20min'), freq='20min')

ref = pd.DataFrame({'dummy':1,'start':intervals[:-1], 'end':intervals[1:]})

(df.assign(dummy=1)
   .merge(ref, on='dummy')
   .query('start < time_begin < end <= time_end')    # your logic is here
   .groupby('start')
   .size()
   .reindex(intervals[:-1], fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
2019-04-04 08:00:00    1
2019-04-04 08:20:00    0
2019-04-04 08:40:00    1
2019-04-04 09:00:00    2
2019-04-04 09:20:00    2
2019-04-04 09:40:00    0
Freq: 20T, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort your values into bins (you will need to find where to start and where to end - in this example I took your 20 minutes as the bin interval), then group by bin and count how many different occurrences of a given column data exist as:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


df = pd.DataFrame({'time_begin': [datetime(2020,10,10,15 + x//4,3*x,3*x) for x in range(20)]})

bin_min = min(df.time_begin).to_pydatetime()
bin_min = datetime(bin_min.year, bin_min.month, bin_min.day, bin_min.hour, (bin_min.minute // 20) * 20)
bin_max = max(df.time_begin)
time_span = bin_max - bin_min
bins = []
accumulated_delta = timedelta(0)
delta_t_bin = timedelta(minutes=20)

while accumulated_delta < time_span + delta_t_bin:
    bins.append(bin_min + accumulated_delta)
    accumulated_delta += delta_t_bin
    

df['bins'] = pd.cut(df.time_begin, bins)
df['my_unique'] = pd.Series(df.groupby('bins').time_begin.unique().apply(lambda x: len(x)).values)
```

Note: the mock data is for test purposes... the naming as well obviously.