# count disasters in dataframe at a certain point in time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which consisists of 4 columns. One of them has a datetime format. I want to count how many events happened at certain point in time. For example, our data looks like

```
       ID           dt_start             dt_end                    disaster             
0   12222732    2019-07-07 07:55:21     2019-07-07 08:15:11        explosion    
1   13510077    2019-07-07 08:01:54     2019-07-07 08:23:54        tsunami  
2   11566221    2019-07-07 08:26:10     2019-07-07 08:44:52        explosion    
3   12949996    2019-07-07 08:38:16     2019-07-07 08:46:12        hurricane   
4   11183882    2019-07-07 09:55:38     2019-07-07 10:02:38        hurricane
```

So i want to count how many events happened at 2019-07-07 at 08:00:00. A disaster is considered to have occurred at 8 am means that it began before 8 am and ended after. But I have no idea how to make these conditions in python in a good way. Is there a way to do this? Our dataframe is much bigger that this example, and I need to count disasters for every 30min, i.e at 8am, 8:30 am etc.

Comment: `(df['dt_start'].le(timestamp) & df['dt_end'].ge(timestamp)).sum()`?

Comment: but my timestamps for le and ge are different, or i can make a list of them and use this in cycle?

Comment: Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64227733/4238408)

Comment: @QuangHoang's first comment seems like the solution to me also. Just create a timestamp datetime obj and sum the number of times it falls between the start/end points. Not sure what you mean for the timestamps for le/ge are different?

Comment: I mean, they are changing, like 8am, 8:30am, 9am..... till 10pm. And the days are different

Comment: You said you have one datetime column but you show two: `dt_start, dt_end`; do they always have identical values, or was that just a quick example (can you fix the example data)? If so you don't even need to read in, or can drop, one of those.

Comment: sorry I forgot to change, now it's fine

Comment: Yes, it seems pretty much similar